# Multiple Pen objects C#

Tags: c#, object, draw, pen

I have a form in which i draw some lines using the Pen object.

I'm wondering if i should use one shared object Pen, or one object Pen per line drawn.

Is is better to use: (one object shared by all lines)

```
Pen green;
green = new Pen(Color,size);
foreach(line to be drawn)
   graphics.DrawLine(green, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Or the following:   (each line is an object)

```
foreach(line to be drawn)
   Pen green = new Pen(Color.Green, 3);
   graphics.DrawLine(green, x1, y1, x2, y2);
   green.Dispose();
```

In fact, both examples do what I want, but i'm wondering what is most recommended in this case.

Note: I'm using C# (WinForms)

Comment: The compiler/jitter should optimize it for you, but since Pen is a win32 unmanaged resource I'd suggest 1 instance with a `using` clause around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you

```
using (var green = new Pen(Color,size)
{
    foreach(line to be drawn)
    {
        graphics.DrawLine(green, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a good option. According to msdn the `using` statement "The using statement obtains one or more resources, executes a statement, and then disposes of the resource." 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this one: [What happens if I don't call Dispose on the pen object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267729/what-happens-if-i-dont-call-dispose-on-the-pen-object)
It seems to be perfectly explained here ...

To keep it short, this one seems to be better :

```
Pen green = new Pen(Color,size);

foreach(line to be drawn)
   graphics.DrawLine(green, x1, y1, x2, y2);

green.Dispose();
```