# Is it OK to create new Pen in Paint function?

Tags: c#, paint

Is creating a new Pen in everytime Paint function called dangerous? Will it use high amount of ram?

So, which one should I use?

```
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black.....
```

or

```
 tpen = new Pen(Color.Black)
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Graphics.DrawLine(tpen
```

Comment: I think, second version is better. Paint event may occur very frequently, so there is no reason to create new Pen every time.

Comment: Dangerous? Yes, it may summon werewolves. High amount of ram? Yes, your machine will crash in seconds. On a more serious note: what do _you_ think? Have you done any research? Did you see [What happens if I don't call Dispose on the pen object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267729/what-happens-if-i-dont-call-dispose-on-the-pen-object)? Do you know what garbage collection is?

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

- If you don't change the `Pen` properties you can simply use `Pens.Black`, a standad `Pen` that you can't even dispose.
- If you know that you will only use a few `Pens` you can keep them while the program runs.
- If you need to create a large or unknown number of `Pens`, maybe to work through a file of drawing actions, then do create them in a `using` clause and don't worry about the time to create them; it happens very fast.

And diposing them is not so much about memory but about `GDI` resources, which are somewhat limited and therefore **must** not leak..

Answer (score 2):

`Pen` implements `IDisposable`, which means that it should be disposed of as soon as it's not needed anymore.  You should not create it directly within the `DrwaLine` call (since there's no way to dispose of it).  It should not be a class member either, assuming it's *only* needed for the `DrawLine` call.

A better approach would be:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using(Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(tpen, ...);
    }
}
```

That way the pen is disposed of even if an exception occurs.

If all you're setting is the color, you *can* inline it by using the static `Pens.Black` property:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, ...);
```

Since the object will be cached by the `Pen` class and you don't need to worry about disposing of it.

Comment: I agree; the benefit of creating a pen as a class field is small - but `using` is essential. In fact you very much should NOT create GDI objects and hang onto them! Create them, use them, dispose them. GDI objects may be limited.

Comment: @MatthewWatson GDI objects may be limited, but saying _"should NOT create GDI objects and hang onto them!"_ I think would depend on the type of object.  `Pens` - sure; `Brushes` sure; `Fonts'  maybe;   `Metafiles` perhaps.  `Bitmaps` depends.  I would not want to keep recreating my offscreen bitmap, 30 FPS in my fancy flicker-free _scrolling chart control_.  The **expense** in **recreating** the object may outweigh simply holding onto it.  The only time I recreate it is if the control is resized.  If the window is not visible or minimized, take a leaf out of DirectX/OpenGL and release them.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Yeah I meant brushes and pens and the ilk, not bitmaps (that would make double-buffering a bit challenging!)